# google sheets - is it possible to match only the "duplicate values" from a column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H8EdAJ3PXzntWvk3jygo8DRRi-Ej4IVEnG0kG6Zj6Og/edit?usp=sharing

in the example sheet above, I would like to populate column H only the duplicate serial numbers found in column E.    Column F has formula that represents wether the value in E is duplicate with True/False - I'm assuming there is a way to use the TRUE value to index and match them over to column H?

Comment: Something like `=UNIQUE(FILTER(E2:E,COUNTIFS(E2:E,E2:E)>1))`? Not sure though...

Comment: hmm will give it a shot, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work for you.  You don't need the helper column.

```
=FILTER(E:E,E:E<>"",COUNTIF(E:E,E:E)>1)
```

Comment: Amazing, Thanks so much Matt! :D -  thanks for adding the example looking at it now to see how it works.